# Set Windows 10 password grace period / timeout

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, uac

I'm using Windows 10 as a member of the Administrators group.

I've set up my group policy for UAC such that Windows [prompts for credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-behavior-of-the-elevation-prompt-for-administrators-in-admin-approval-mode) whenever something requires elevated access.

On more than once occasion, I've needed elevated access repeatedly in a short time interval. For example: when experimenting with setting up shared internet connections, (re)moving files on a protected drive, etc. In many situations, these actions are not part of a bulk operation, so an "All as administrator" option is not available. On these occasions, I have to type my PIN every 2 seconds, sometimes dozens of times.

On Linux, as a `sudoer` using `sudo`, there is a configurable timeout period such that after typing your password, you can use `sudo` for a short while without having to re-type the password every time.

So, I'm looking for the Windows analog for that mechanism. Does such a concept exist in the Windows world? Or am I trying too hard to make Windows behave like Linux and am I just approaching the problem "all wrong"?

Googling `grace period` or `pin timeout` and similar terms have not proven very fruitful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't have such an option to completely disable
User Account Control (UAC).
Microsoft made this annoying on purpose and by design, in order to
discourage you from doing elevation too frequently.
Linux took rather the approach that people know what they are doing
(and if they don't then it's their fault).

I can think of these possibilities:

- Work in a Command Prompt (cmd) or PowerShell that is Run as Administrator.
  Windows Explorer will not work in Admin mode, so if you need this then you
  should use some
  [alternative file manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm)
  that can be run in elevated mode.
- Temporarily
  [Enable or Disable User Account Control (UAC) in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112488-enable-disable-user-account-control-uac-windows.html).
- Use the built-in Administrator account. However, there is a good
  security reason why this account is disabled.

Comment: Thanks, half-expected an answer along these lines...Thanks for the tips though

Answer (score 1):

At it's most simple you can elevate an hta hosting a folderview.

Call it `folder.hta`.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="file:///c:/" width="100%" height="99%">
</body>
</html>
```

This is explorer like but you can't go up a folder only down.

Note the initial folder is expressed as an HTML path not a Windows path.